# South African Refugee Travel Document

Tags: visas, usa, applications, south-africa, refugees

I am trying to apply for visa student for the US, but I will have the South African  Refugee Travel Document instead of a regular passport. I am worried that they might not be able to issue a visa for me. What are the requirements for people like me to get a visa to US with a South African Refugee Passport?

Comment: Related: [Can the holder of a South African Refugee ID visit the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119943/can-the-holder-of-a-south-african-refugee-id-visit-the-usa) and [Traveling to USA using the South african refugee travel document](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143512/traveling-to-usa-using-the-south-african-refugee-travel-document) and possibly others too.

Answer (score 1):

US law and other materials routinely refer to "passports", but that term is defined to include other passport-like documents that do not bear the title "passport."  The definition is at [8 USC 1101(a)(30)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#a_30):

> The term “passport” means any travel document issued by competent authority showing the bearer’s origin, identity, and nationality if any, which is valid for the admission of the bearer into a foreign country.

This definition applies to the entire Immigration and Nationality Act.  If the US refuses your visa, the kind of travel document you are using will not be the reason for the refusal.